# Ya no sale la rama y ahora sale el id del commit

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Estaba haciendo unos ajustes y me di cuenta que algo estaba mal, entonces...

- regresé a un commit anterior
  `git checkout ada9d192ba9216011a5a25c14faaab6fa1ef1888`

- salió esto ->

```
HEAD is now at ada9d19 Estructura de seccion paneles en index.html
M       index.html
M       styles.css
```

y ahora la dirección cambió -> `---@DESKTOP-QAKT4 MINGW ~/--/---/---/-- ((ada9d19...)`
cambió el main por -> `((ada9d19...))`

me arrepentí, pero ahora ¿cómo le hago para regresar a la rama main?

Answer (score 0):

Tu *HEAD* esta "desacoplado", puedes volver a situarte en la cabecera de la rama con:

```
git checkout nombre_rama
```

para el caso

```
git checkout main
```

Comment: Esta es la respuesta correcta y ya le hice un _upvote_, sin embargo, creo que merece una explicación porque es uno de los mejores features de git: Las ramas son apuntadores a revisiones. Cuando estás trabajando sobre una rama y haces un _commit_, git crea una nueva revisión y _mueve la rama_ a esa revisión. Pero git en el fondo trabaja con **revisiones**, las ramas son para nuestra comodidad. Cuando hiciste `git checkout xxxx` (con la revisión), git te llevó a esa revisión **pero** sin tener una rama en la que trabajar (eso se llama **detached HEAD**, en inglés).